# How can I make it so that the content view updates when the user taps on something with .onTapGesture?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to re-crate a simple app from code.org, and while trying, I came across the issue that I can't change the screen how I imagined.

I wanted it so that theres 2 ContentViews. One is for the home page, and the second is for the first question (I will add more in the future).

In the Home view, there is a rectangle with some text inside. There is a .onTapGesture argument under the Rectangle(), in which it should change the @State variable to Question1() from Home().

However, it says that it can't find the State Variable in the scope. I also tried EnvironmentalObject, but I don't know how to format it, and to be honest, I think it's because I'm not searching for the right thing.

Here's the entire project, in which should be run on an iPhone 12 Pro simulator:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var showingScreen = Home()
    var body: some View {
        showingScreen
    }
}

struct Home: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(red: 115 / 255, green: 235 / 255, blue: 156 / 255)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Text("The Ultimate Pet Chooser!")
                    .bold()
                    .font(.system(size: 50))
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 77 / 255, green: 87 / 255, blue: 95 / 255))
                    .position(x: 200, y: 80)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color(red: 130 / 255, green: 0 / 255, blue: 255 / 255))
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 250)
                    .position(x: 200, y: 150)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        showingScreen = Question1()
                    }
                Text("Click here            to start!")
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .font(.system(size: 50))
                    .bold()
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .position(x: 200, y: -105)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Question1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
    }
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have some confusion over state in SwiftUI (in particular, what `EnvironmentObject` is -- you shouldn't be storing a `View` in it). I'd recommend you check out the Apple SwiftUI tutorials (and maybe Hacking with Swift's SwiftUI tutorials as well). Storing `@State` will be covered early on in both.

Comment: the tutorial is at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/  Get a good understanding of the basics first, otherwise you will keep struggling to build your App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand what you try to achieve, you want to have a `Home` view and it shall provide a button (or so) to switch to the `Question View`?
Is that understanding is correct?
If so, here are 2 approaches you could follow:

## Navigation View with Navigation Link

You have 2 views `HomeView()` and `QuestionView()`. The `HomeView()` contains a **NavigationView** and within that NavigationView you have a **NavigationLink** to open the `QuestionView()`. If you press the that link the `QuestionView()` slides in from the right side. In a NavigationView you can set up some options, for example a title, the appearance of the title, a back button (is automatically there, etc...)

This approach would look like:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  PetChooser
//
//  Created by Sebastian Fox on 30.08.22.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HomeView()
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {
            VStack(){
                Text("The Ultimate Pet Chooser!")
                    .font(.system(size: 50))
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 77/255, green: 87/255, blue: 95/255))
                NavigationLink(destination: QuestionView()) {
                    Text("Click here to start!")
                        .font(.system(size: 50))
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .clipShape(Rectangle()) // actually, that is not even necessary, the frame makes it a rectangle anyway.
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 250)
                        .background(Color(red: 130/255, green: 0/255, blue: 255/255))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct QuestionView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Here the first Question")
                .font(.system(size: 50))
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 77/255, green: 87/255, blue: 95/255))
        }
    }
}
```

Here a gif of how it looks like

[image: NaviagtionView approach]

## @State var to handle displayed view controlled by buttons#

In this approach you also have the two views `HomeView()` and `QuestionView()`additional to that you have one var in your `ContentView()` that handles which view will be shown. In this approach the variable that handles the selected view will be initialized to show the `HomeView()` (I created an Enum with the available views, but you can use Int e.g.: `HomeView()` = 0 and `QuestionView()` = 1, or even String values as well). The `HomeView()` now has a got a button that changes the value of variable that handles the shown view to the value that represents the `QuestionView()` (on the `QuestionView()` there is a button to change the value of the variable to show the `HomeView()`. To make the variable from `ContentView()` avaibalew in the (Sub)Views, there is a binding, so you can access the variable from all the views:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  PetChooser
//
//  Created by Sebastian Fox on 30.08.22.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedPage: SelectedPage = .home
    var body: some View {
        // YOU CAN DO A SWITCH CASE AS WELL
        if selectedPage == .home {
            HomeView(selectedPage: $selectedPage)
        } else if selectedPage == .question {
            QuestionView(selectedPage: $selectedPage)
        } else {
            VStack() {
                Text("ERROR, PAGE DOES NOT EXIST")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    
    @Binding var selectedPage: SelectedPage
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {
            VStack(){
                
                Text("The Ultimate Pet Chooser!")
                    .font(.system(size: 50))
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 77/255, green: 87/255, blue: 95/255))
                
                Button(action: {
                    selectedPage = .question
                }) {
                    HStack() {
                            Text("Click here to start!")
                                .font(.system(size: 50))
                                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    .clipShape(Rectangle()) // actually, that is not even necessary, the frame makes it a rectangle anyway
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 250)
                    .background(Color(red: 130/255, green: 0/255, blue: 255/255))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct QuestionView: View {
    
    @Binding var selectedPage: SelectedPage
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Here the first Question")
                .font(.system(size: 50))
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 77/255, green: 87/255, blue: 95/255))
            
            Button(action: {
                selectedPage = .home
            }) {
                HStack() {
                        Text("back")
                            .font(.system(size: 50))
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .clipShape(Rectangle())
                .frame(width: 300, height: 250)
                .background(Color(red: 130/255, green: 0/255, blue: 255/255))
            }
        }
    }
}

enum SelectedPage {
    case home
    case question
}
```

And the gif

[image: @State var handling]